# Field template in theme based on Garland

Tags: 7, entities, theming

I have problem with template for field "field_is_new" in Drupal 7.
My_Theme is a modification of the Garland theme. (I don't know if it's important.)

I have created a template for this field in my theme folder ("My_Theme/templates/field--field-is-new.tpl.php").

In template.php, I added:

```
function My_Theme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
  // Add specific suggestions that can override the default implementation.
  array_unshift($variables['theme_hook_suggestions'], 'field__' . $variables['element']['#field_name']);
}
```

I cleared the cache, and rebuilt the theme.

I was thinking it's good way to do this, but it's not working.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your preprocess function is not necessary in this situation because Drupal's default behavior is using this sort of files. Try `print_r($variables['theme_hook_suggestions']);` and see all relevant suggestions.

Your problem is the wrong filename; try field--field_is_new.tpl.php instead.

The general recommendation is using theme functions:

```
function theme_field__field_taxonomy($vars) {
  $output = '';

  foreach ($vars['items'] as $delta => $item) {
    $array = explode(';',$item['#markup']);

    if (count($array)) {
      $output = '<ul class="' . $vars['classes'] . ' clearfix"' . $vars['attributes'] . '>';
      foreach ($array as $value) {
          $output .= '<li>' . trim($value) . '</li>';
      }
      $output .= '</ul>';
    };
  }

  return $output;
}
```